# I can't install virtualbox on Debian11 - Windows User

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, docker, docker-compose

I'm a Windows-user and I have installed Debian11 through the Windows Store.

I'm struggling and failing with installing VirtualBox on Debian11.

I downloaded VirtualBox 6.1(.28) from here: [VirtualBox 6.1 for Debian11](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.28/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.28-147628%7EDebian%7Ebullseye_amd64.deb) and I installed it with the command:

`sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.28-147628~Debian~bullseye_amd64.deb`

getting these messages:

```
    Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-6.1.
(Reading database ... 79878 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-6.1_6.1.28-147628~Debian~bullseye_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.28-147628~Debian~bullseye) ...
Setting up virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.28-147628~Debian~bullseye) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.0-1) ...
```

After that it seems that VirtualBox is installed but I can't use VirtualBox for creating a docker-machine (the reason for which I needed VirtualBox), indeed if I use on the bash this command:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox temp.sysadmin.local
```

I got:

```
    Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is \"WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module\\n         available for the current kernel (4.4.0-19041-Microsoft) or it failed to\\n         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by\\n\\n           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig\\n\\n         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\\n6.1.28r147628\". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org"
```

Thank you all in advance for any hints.

Comment: Why are you trying to install an hypervisor inside what is, in essence, a virtual machine? What exactly are you trying to accomplish with Virtualbox?

Comment: Why not install VirtualBox directly in Windows?

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for your comment. I have to use a "docker-compose up" command in Debian and I think I need VirtualBox for creating a Docker machine

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your comment. I used Debian on Windows to install Python 3.8.8, a specific version for using a module I want to work with. In Windows I have Anaconda with Python 3.8.5 and I can't update it (without creating virtual environment) to Python 3.8.8.

Comment: No, Docker doesn't require Virtualbox.

Comment: @ChanganAuto if I use "docker-compose up" on Debian I got: "ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.".
Then I use "docker-machine start default" and I got: " Docker machine "default" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one. "

Then I try to create a docker-machine with "docker-machine create default" and I got: Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

This is why I think VirtualBox is needed

Comment: You need to take a step back, read the Docker documentation, maybe this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers as well, and then try again. Your comments suggest that you are confused about the tools you need to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the kernel headers and disable the secure boot.

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
/sbin/vboxconfig
```